# Google Chrome opening leaves window shadow at first

Tags: 16.04, gnome, google-chrome, chromium, ubuntu-gnome

When I'm opening the Chromium, it leaves a shadow before opening and after 2 seconds the chromium window showing. Shadow size is always the size of the unmaximized chromium window (even if chromium opening at maximized size, at first it leaves unmaximized size of window shadow and then it opens the maximized window).

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04, with GNOME Shell 3.18.5 and Nvidia 375.39 driver.

You can see this behavior here:

1. Desktop without any problem:

[image: GNOME desktop]

2. Clicking on chromium icon to run.
3. It shows the shadow in size of the window at first:

[image: chromim shadow at start]

4. after around 2 seconds the window is showing up:

[image: Chromium loaded]

and the shadow mark isn't there anymore.

**I noticed when I'm enabling "system title bar and borders" from settings->appearance, this kind of problem doesn't happening anymore.**

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is known bug for Chromium and Firefox. They both leave this shadow.
On [Chromium bugs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=18668) you can find this fix, but I´m not sure if it´s gonna help:

`gconftool-2 --set --type=float

/apps/compiz/plugins/decoration/allscreens/options/shadow_opacity 0.7
gconftool-2 --set --type=float

/apps/compiz/plugins/decoration/allscreens/options/shadow_radius 25.0
gconftool-2 --set --type=string 
/apps/compiz/plugins/decoration/allscreens/options/shadow_color 
/apps/compiz/plugins/decoration/allscreens/options/shadow_color #000000ff
gconftool-2 --set --type=int

/apps/compiz/plugins/decoration/allscreens/options/shadow_x_offset 0
gconftool-2 --set --type=int

/apps/compiz/plugins/decoration/allscreens/options/shadow_y_offset 5
gconftool-2 --set --type=string 
/apps/compiz/plugins/decoration/allscreens/options/command /usr/bin/compiz-
decorator
gtk-window-decorator --replace 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null & disown`

Comment: I think the bug you mentioned here is different from the problem I have. because I'm not using Compiz. as I mentioned on my Question I'm using GNOME 3.  didn't install Compiz. I don't have this problem on Unity or XFCE. I don't know why this kind of behavior is happening :(